# Cobordism theory for piecewise-linear (PL) and topological manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, cobordism

The Cobordism theory was originally developed by René Thom for smooth manifolds (i.e., differentiable), but there are now also versions for [piecewise-linear and topological manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism#Cobordism_of_piecewise_linear_and_topological_manifolds).

I know the Cobordism theory for smooth manifolds, for example, given two $d$-dimensional manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$, we can ask whether they are (co)bordant via a $d+1$-dimensional manifolds $W$, such that
$$
\partial W= M_1 \sqcup M_2.
$$
For example,

- (1) 5-dimensional Dold manifold and Wu manifold are manifolds which are [cobordant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) to each other via 5-dimensional bordism group:
  $$
  \Omega^{SO}_5=\mathbb{Z}_2.
  $$
  In other words, my interpretation is that the Dold and Wu manifolds are both the nontrivial generators of $\Omega^{SO}_5=\mathbb{Z}_2$.
- (2) For example, consider an oriented bordism, bordisms between $4$-manifolds. The signature $\sigma(X^{4k})$ of an oriented $4k$-manifold $X^{4k}$ is an oriented bordism invariant. Now $\sigma(S^4) = 0$
  and $\sigma( C P^2) = 1.$ So $S^4$ and $ C P^2$ are not oriented bordant. In fact, $\Omega_4^{{SO}} \cong \Bbb Z$ with generator $[C P^2]$.

So in the above, I give one example (Dold manifold and Wu manifold) that are cobordant via $\Omega^{SO}_5$, and another counterexample where $S^4$ and $ C P^2$ are not oriented bordant $\Omega_4^{{SO}}$.

> **Questions**: Now, I am not familiar with Cobordism theory of piecewise linear and topological manifolds.
>
> - Can we explain how the cobordant of piecewise-linear (PL) and topological manifolds is defined, in a simple manner?
> - Can we give one example and another counterexample, in dimensions 3, 4 and 5,  such that two PL topological manifolds are cobordant or not cobordant, respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The definition is no different, just replace the phrase "smooth manifold" everywhere with "PL" or "topological" manifold.

2) The book "The classifying spaces for surgery and cobordism of manifolds" by Madsen and Milgram gives a calculation of *the oriented version* of  $\Omega^{\text{Top}}_*/\text{Tors}$ as a ring; they prove it is additionally isomorphic to $\Omega^{\text{PL}}_*/\text{Tors}$. I am not going to try to recover it from the book, though.

3) PL = Smooth in dimensions up through and including 6, so there is no difference in the corresponding bordism groups in degree up to 5. Every topological 3-manifold has a smooth structure, and every smooth 3-manifold is null-bordant. I gave a reference for an example of a topological 4-manifold that is not null-bordant in an MO question you a asked before [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/306585/40804); in fact the calculation of  the oriented version of $\Omega^{\text{Top}}_4$; the Kirby-Seibenmann invariant is an unoriented bordism invariant as well.

I don't know the answer for the group of unoriented bordism classes $\Omega_5^{\text{Top}}$. One should be able to argue in the oriented case as follows: there is an oriented bordism to a simply connected manifold, obtained by an oriented surgery on some sequence of nontrivial loops. Then the class of simply connected 5-manifolds has been classified, and in fact they are all smoothable. Hence every oriented closed topological 5-manifold is oriented-bordant to a smooth one.

Comment: In the topological case, the unoriented bordism group $\Omega_*^{Top}$ is just a free polynomial algebra $\mathbb{Z}_2[x_2, x_4, x_5, \dots]$ over $x_n$ with $n\not = 2^k-1$, where $\deg x_n = n$. The proof is due to Dold and involves using the Pontryagin-Thom construction to reduce the problem to one about a certain classifying space, then using some algebraic machinery to compute its homotopy groups.

Comment: thanks, +1, this is a really nice discussion.

Comment: Mike, you had a great comment about Kirby-Siebenmann invariant - why did you remove it? sorry?

Comment: @wonderich I wasn't sure I believed it. I would have to think more carefully.

Comment: @anomaly Is the implicit claim here that $\Omega_*^{\text{Top}} \to \Omega_*$ is an isomorphism? I do not think this is true. Actually, Hsu's paper in the question I linked states that $\Omega_4^{\text{Top}} \cong (\Bbb Z/2)^3$, with the third factor given by the Kirby-Seibenmann invariant. (He writes this as $\eta_4$ and this is his Corollary 2.4(c).)

Comment: I've seen that paper. Aren't the relevant classes $x_2^2, x_4$, and $x_2^2 + x_4$?

Comment: @anomaly Those aren't linearly independent. Your ring has only two linearly independent generators in degree 4.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Hmm. Let me look up the details later; that result is a fairly well-known one, but I might be thinking of one of the many other cobordism groups.

Comment: @anomaly I think the result you give is the smooth case. My gut feel is that you have to be very careful talking about Pontryagin-Thom in the topological case, because you need some notion of transversality. Maybe via Kirby-Seibenmann's results on topological manifolds this is fine in high dimensions, but I don't know this stuff well. I would guess that PL is easier and that one passes to Top using PL/TOP = K(Z/2, 3) somehow. Unfortunately I have never actually looked at the Madsen-Milgram book in more detail than a very quick skim.

Comment: Hmm, ditto for everything you said. For that matter, aren't we starting with the tangent bundle in the construction, which doesn't exist for an arbitrary topological manifold? (I think Milnor's work on microbundles came afterward, and I don't know that they actually have all the expected properties.)

Comment: I think the microbundle idea should work ok in the PL case. Surely the MM book touches on these points, so I think I will peruse it tonight. If they have anything about the unoriented bordism ring in there I will try to find it too, but it seems such a result would have to be conditional before Hsu's paper. If you have any interest in trying to find/recover the results from the literature, feel free to email me. It would be really surprising if this question was open.

Comment: Awesome, I will; feel free to email me too. (Might be a bit of a delay, though; I'm not going to be around over the weekend.)

Comment: Wait, the generators of the $x_n$ above are $\mathbb{RP}^n$ for $n$ even and a space like $S^p \times \mathbb{CP}^q / ((x, z) \to (-x, \overline{z})$ in the odd case. They're both smooth. So yeah, that must be the smooth cobordism ring.

Comment: thanks for the answers!